# How to get silos in Slime Rancher?

Tags: slime-rancher

I’m replaying Slime Rancher and struggling more than in previous plays because I don’t have access to silos. In previous games, I did whatever unlocks them without noticing. I just bought the 7-Zee reward that gives you the 100-unit vac expansion, and my slimes are producing an unmanageable amount of plort. What can I do to enable the fabrication of silos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silos are not an unlockable. You can go to an empty ranch plot, and select Silo in the build menu, same as you would a corral.